# Computer freezes for 1 second then goes back

Tags: video, graphics-card, freeze

The problem: image freezes for circa one second, nothing in video works during this time, but sound works. If I'm watching a video (in google chrome), the video will keep going after the freeze, if playing a game, I need to restart the game.

It seems like the freezing accours the most when I watch a video (in google chrome) and at the same time have a game opened. But it has happend when only having a game opened.

The weird part is, that I have played more performance demanding games in the past. With no problem. No I play a game which should be more or less capable of running on any computer. Maybe its the combination of watching a video in google chrome and the game. It is like the video card "reboots" of some sort.

I have played around with the graphic settings in the game, but I does not solve the problem.

I have an Asus laptop with nvidia 960m, intel graphix 4600, i7 4720, 8 gig ram, set to high perfomance in windows. Drivers has the latest update.

According to windows I am currently using 15 % of cpu 45 % ram at this moment having both the game and video rolling.

I found some logg book in windows, and here you can see all the times when the computer has freezed as a I described.
[image: I found some logg book in windows, and here you can see all the times when the computer has freezed as a I described]

Comment: Many laptops don't expose commonly addressable sensors, but can you get readings on CPU and GPU temp when its being naughty?

Comment: I will try to get a reading from cpu@FrankThomas

Comment: I know you've got latest drivers but what drivers? If using the drivers from MS update, don't. Go to manufacturer website to check.  For graphic, audio and chipset

Comment: well, there isn't a lot a user can do about an app hang event. see here for a description of the event from MS: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd744765(v=vs.85).aspx  what is the Tibia client?

Comment: I downloaded them from nvidias website. @dave

Comment: The tibia client is the game I play. @FrankThomas

Comment: See if there is a patch or email them direct

Comment: Are you saying that the game is causing all the trouble? @Dave

Comment: check out the MSDN link above.